# Fullcalendar select works on double tap in mobile

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, react-rails

I have used fullcalendar library with React on Rails. Currently on mobile devices the 'select' callback gets triggered on double tap.

https://gist.github.com/RORingBBK/9d943068cee3e5ac1006d9ec936284c9

The select related options that I have used are

```
selectable: true,
selectLongPressDelay: 0,
unselectCancel: ".new_date",
```

And then the **select** callback itself as shown on attached gist.
I have added ***debugger*** and checked when exactly **select** callback is triggered. Mostly it happens on double tap on mobile devices on particular date. But sometimes it works with single tap.

Is there a way to resolve this issue and make it work on single tap?

P.S. Ignore the conditions inside fullcalendar callback methods. They are customized according to app requirements. Thanks.

Comment: I was able to fix this problem by adding unselect after select callback and doing some js hacks with adding class for highlighting selected dates.